# Connecting the first two nodes with an edge from two RDDs in GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using GraphX for the first time and I want to build a Graph incrementally. So I need to connect  the first two nodes to an edge knowing that I have 2 RDDs (each one has a single value):

```
firstRDD: RDD[((Int, Array[Int]), ((VertexId, Array[Int]), Int))]
secondRDD: RDD[((Int, Array[Int]), ((VertexId, Array[Int]), Int))]
```

I want to connect the first **VertexId** with the second one.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Are you saying you have two RDDs, with an equal number of rows. In each row is a VertexId, and you want to pair up one VertexId from the first RDD with one from the second RDD?

Comment: Exactly, that's what i want to do, i want the Graph built  when i pair up the two "VertexId"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you use `map` and `case` statements to pick out the VertexIds, then, use `RDD.zip` to stitch them together, then another `map` to create the final EdgeRDD:

```
firstRDD.map{ 
  case ((junk1,junk2), ((vertex1, junk3), junk4)) => vertex1
}.zip(
  secondRDD.map{
    case ((junk1,junk2), ((vertex2, junk3), junk4)) => vertex2 
  }
).map{ case(vertex1, vertex2) => Edge(vertex1, vertex2, 0) }
```

Comment: Hi David, can I have your email adress please??
I have a problem and I thnik that you can help me to resolve it ! thank you in advance